# TestNG - Selenium Java > Data Provider Iteration and Return to previous @Test

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am seeking some help once again on dataProviders in TestNG.

I delve into my design quickly.

- I am using the dataProvider1 for return a data set containing a
  hashmap, this data set contains one or more entries.
- The first method or @Test1 iterates through this list, for the first 
  entry, index 0. based on this info it sets some information and updates an array.
- dataProvider2 then executes and returns another data set array containing my workflow (Login,create etc).
- @Test2 then does what it needs to do by preparing some data for downstream.

BUT, here is my challenge : because dataProvider1 is still within the first iteration, I want to return to dataProvider1 and then move to the next  value in the iteration and then send that on etc.

Please can someone help me, if you need more info i can update the post

```
  @DataProvider(name = "ExecutionOffersFromExcel")
  public static Iterator < Object[] > buildExecutionListFromExcel() throws Exception {
      testCaseArray3 = new DataSetController().createExecutionListFromExcel(dataSetfilename, "SpecialOffers");
      return testCaseArray3.entrySet().stream().map(input - > new Object[] {
          input.getKey(), input.getValue()
      }).iterator();
  }


@Test(dataProvider = "ExecutionOffersFromExcel")
  public void ExecutionOffersFromExcel(String sExecutionScenario, ArrayList < OffersExecutionModel > readInputData) throws Exception {
      String Code = null;
      String OfferType = null;
      String OfferCat = null;
      String Incentivise;
      String ExecuteScenario;
      List < String > specialsValidation = null;

      for (OffersExecutionModel offer: readInputData) {
          Code = offer.Code;
          OfferType = offer.OfferType;
          OfferCat = offer.OfferCat;
          Incentivise = offer.Incentivise;

          ScenarioOfferringCode = OfferType.toString();
          getOfferBaseTest = new CustomerCode(CODE);
          specialsValidation = Arrays.asList(OfferCat.trim().split(","));

          for (String validate: specialsValidation) {
              switch (validate.toUpperCase()) {
                  case "C1":
                      workSheet.add("Cat1 Offer Default Offer");
                      break;
                  case "C2":
                      workSheet.add("Cat2  Offer Default Offer");
                      break;
                  case "C3":
                      workSheet.add("Cat3  Offer Default Offer");
                      break;
              }
              // break;
          }
          getCustomerBaseTest.setOffer_Type(workSheet);
          incentiviseThis = true;
          break;
      }
  }
```

This is my execution model, containing 3 entries of offers, basically my driver script / controller script. What I need is that when the next data provider is invoked it must execute the workflow for offer1 entry. then come back here for the next offer. This works perfectly fine for single offers now that I want to iterate through a list of offers for execution.

readInputData - this will contain 1..* offer entries to execute.

Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using the InvocationCount attribute, by setting this value to 17 there is no need to read the the data set again (ExcelSheet ), InvocationCount is set to a value in this case 17, will inform the script to perform another Iteration.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "ExecutionOffersFromExcel", invocationCount=17)
public void ExecutionOffersFromExcel(String sExecutionScenario, ArrayList < OffersExecutionModel > readInputData)
```